# Explain the scope of L and R in this merge sort code?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def mergeSort(arr): 
if len(arr) >1: 
    mid = len(arr)//2 # Finding the mid of the array 
    L = arr[:mid] # Dividing the array elements  
    R = arr[mid:] # into 2 halves 

    
    mergeSort(L) # Sorting the first half 
    mergeSort(R) # Sorting the second half 

    i = j = k = 0
      
    # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] 
    while i < len(L) and j < len(R): 
        if L[i] < R[j]: 
            arr[k] = L[i] 
            i+= 1
        else: 
            arr[k] = R[j] 
            j+= 1
        k+= 1
      
    # Checking if any element was left 
    while i < len(L): 
        arr[k] = L[i] 
        i+= 1
        k+= 1
      
    while j < len(R): 
        arr[k] = R[j] 
        j+= 1
        k+= 1
    return arr
```

How does the values of L and R change depending on the changes in the values of L and R in recursive functions, although they are independent variables? Can anyone explain this in detail?

Comment: `L` and `R` are always local variables, but `mergesort` mutates the list you pass in, e.g. `arr[k] = L[i]`. And note, you are making copies of each sublist.

Comment: compare these three functions: `def f(L): L.append(3)` and `def g(L): L = L + [4]` and `def h(L): L[0] = 5`. Try them out: `L = [1, 2]; print(L); f(L); print(L); L = [1, 2]; print(L); g(L); print(L); L = [1, 2]; print(L); h(L); print(L); `

Comment: Your comment `# Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[]` is misleading. The while loop following this comment is not copying data **to** L and R, but **from** L and R.

Answer (score 1):

In python, a list is a mutable object, thus here L and R are passed by reference, the "`return arr`" at the end is not even necessary. It means the list is modified even through the recursive function calls.
Take a debugger and study the pivotal moment where the merge sort algorithm has split every items and starts ordering, you will get a much better idea of how it works.

There is something wrong with the indentation of your code though. You need to indent all your code under your function declaration, except the `return` line.

Comment: I'm pretty convinced **all** lines starting from `if len(arr) >1:` need one more indentation level, not just the first 6

Comment: You're right, otherwise L and R would not be known in the rest of the algorithm. The return line is right though.Thanks Stef, i edited my answer.